# How to filter/extract invalid timestamp values from spark dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of XYZ records that consists of a timestamp column, that timestamp column consists of invalid values as shown below

[image]

This I have to create two dataframes one that consists of valid timestamp values and other with invalid timestamp values as shown below:

valid df should look like below:

[image]

Invalid records df should have values of invalid timestamp:

[image]

Couldn't know how to filter this way using pyspark. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use to_date/to_timestamp method to change the column type to date/timestamp type. If input date is valid to_date will return date in spark's default date format, if not null will be returned. Based on this behavior we can extract both valid and invalid dates.

```
df = # Input dataframe

date_df = df.withColumn("validdatecheck",to_date("modified_date", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"))

invalid_date_df = date_df.where(date_df.validdatecheck.isNull())
valid_date_df = date_df.where(date_df.validdatecheck.isNotNull())
```

## UPDATE

In Spark 3.1, `from_unixtime`, `unix_timestamp`,`to_unix_timestamp`, `to_timestamp` and `to_date` will fail if the specified datetime pattern is invalid. In Spark 3.0 or earlier, they result NULL. Check documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-30-to-31).

To switch back to previous behavior you can use below configuration.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
```